# All traffic except LAN to go through remote access VPN- WIndows 7/8

Tags: windows, vpn

I want all internet traffic except the local (192.168.10.0/24) to pass through the remote access VPN connection.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That can't possibly work. The VPN would implode due to recursive encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

This should be trivial to set up:

1. Start VPN
2. Check that the VPN has assigned the default gateway to itself.
   (This usually is an option in your VPN software. Check for split tunneling and turn it off).
3. Make sure you have a route to the local network. If needed do a manual route add 192.168.10.0 with a higher priority.

Comment: That will cause the VPN to use itself to reach its other endpoint. Boom.